# Retrieving first few bytes from a huge file via $http.get

Tags: angularjs, http

How can we prevent $http.get from downloading all the contents of a huge text file that is 500mb in filesize? Let's say, I only want to retrieve the first 50k

Comment: I would do this by creating a service/api on the server side to return the first 50k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Front-end download specific bytes from file on server:**

Try the following code to download first 50 MB from your file:

```
$http.get('www.example.com/someapi', {
  headers: {'Range': "bytes=0-49999"}
});
```

Read more about [Range-request-header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#range-request-header)

**Back-end divide file on server to parts:**

If you want to divide your huge file to parts, and download them from angular, so you can make routes for each part as the following:

```
http://rootPath.com/downloadFile?part:=id
```

Then you can send get request to  download wanted part(50 MB), that'll tell the server which  part of huge file the front-end  wants.

Comment: `Accept-Ranges` is a response header, not a request header, and `bytes-unit` and `byte-range` aren't headers at all.  You linked to the correct document, but you misread it.

Comment: The correct request header for the first 50,000 bytes is `Range: bytes=0-49999`

Comment: @hobbs Read the intro of site: "This section defines the syntax and semantics of all standard HTTP/1.1 header fields. For entity-header fields, both sender and recipient refer to either the client or the server, depending on who sends and who receives the entity."

Comment: Yes, and you're completely misinterpreting that sentence, as well as the grammar.

Comment: I almost forgot about my post. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you so much folks! I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @hobbs You're right, I searched about it, and this [range-header-request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#range-request-header) helps me :), Thanks alot man :)

Comment: Thank you so much folks! It worked. I updated my Apache configuration too since it was being blocked due to CORS issue.

Answer (score 2):

If the server supports Range requests, you can send the header `Range: bytes=0-49999` or however many bytes you want.